# How to create a JQL filter to list all tickets worked on last workday?

Tags: filter, jira, jql

I am currently trying to create a filter, that lists all tickets I logged my work on for the last workday. Unfortunately I don"t have any gadgets for that and am not able to get them installed.

Currently I am using a filter for the worklog of the last week:

```
worklogAuthor = currentUser() AND worklogDate >= startOfDay(-1w)
```

It is fairly simple to extend this filter to ignore the current day and to replcae `startOfDay(-1w)` with `startOfDay(-1d)`, but this would not take weekends into account. Furthermore I am not checking who logged the work on the date.

How would you solve this?

Comment: Did you try `startOfWeek()` method?

Comment: Like `startOfWeek(-1)`

Comment: I don't get what that would solve. Could you please elaborate that thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Liping Huang's question, this seems to work for me to catch issues updated today or last workday, so an analogous formulation might do for you:

```
worklogDate >= startOfDay(-1d) or (worklogDate >= startOfWeek(-2d) and worklogDate >= startOfDay(-3d))
```

(This assumes a Sunday week start and Monday-Friday working days.)

EDIT: Correction based on comments:

```
worklogDate >= startOfDay(-1d) or (worklogDate <= startOfWeek(1d) and worklogDate >= startOfDay(-3d))
```

EDIT AGAIN: Bombproofing based on comments:

For Sunday week starts (North America, Australia?):

```
(worklogDate >= startOfDay(-1d) or (worklogDate >= startOfWeek(-2d) and worklogDate <= startOfWeek(1d) and worklogDate >= startOfDay(-3d))) and worklogDate < startOfDay()
```

For Monday week starts (Europe?):

```
(worklogDate >= startOfDay(-1d) OR worklogDate >= startOfWeek(-3d) AND worklogDate <= startOfWeek() AND worklogDate >= startOfDay(-3d)) AND worklogDate < startOfDay()
```

Comment: This expression can be simplified as `updatedDate >= startOfDay(-3d)`. It returns all logs of the last 3 days. On friday it would return all logs updated since Tuesday. That is not what I wanted though.

Comment: That simplification doesn't do the same thing as my query; try it on a Tuesday-Friday and see!

Comment: I tried it today (Friday) and it did exactly as I said. The problem is that the `OR` concatenation is a logically one. This means it yields all results as an `AND` plus those which only satisfy one predicate. Furthermore `updatedDate >= startOfDay(-3d)` will include both `updatedDate >= startOfWeek(-2d) ` and `updatedDate >= startOfWeek(-1d) `. Therefore my previous claim stands that it can be simplified to `updatedDate >= startOfWeek(-3d) `.

Comment: Sorry, you're quite right; I've added another version.

Comment: I changed `updatedDate` to `worklogDate` to apply to the question. Once the review is finished, I will accept this answer.

Comment: I have to revoke my acceptance of this answer, because today (Thursday) I am getting tickets work logged on yesterday __and__ Monday.

Comment: Very strange; I'll put in an edit that should bombproof it. One issue is that according to the [StartOfWeek function reference](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-functions-reference-764478342.html#Advancedsearching-functionsreference-startOfWeekstartOfWeek()), your week start day is probably Monday instead of Sunday as it is here.

Comment: Thank you, I will test it and come back to you on Thursday.